# Why is my Type not being Serialized correctly by the XmlSerializer

Tags: xml-serialization

The intial problem was that when I called a webservice ( asmx) methos with a type the type was always going through as null . Inspecting the Soap confirmed that the type was going as an empty element. So I tried a simple test.
Here is my type which of course has been generated from WSDL

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://dto12.api.echosign")]
public partial class SendDocumentInteractiveOptions {

    private bool authoringRequestedField;

    private bool authoringRequestedFieldSpecified;

    private bool autoLoginUserField;

    private bool autoLoginUserFieldSpecified;

    private bool noChromeField;

    private bool noChromeFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool authoringRequested {
        get {
            return this.authoringRequestedField;
        }
        set {
            this.authoringRequestedField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool authoringRequestedSpecified {
        get {
            return this.authoringRequestedFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.authoringRequestedFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool autoLoginUser {
        get {
            return this.autoLoginUserField;
        }
        set {
            this.autoLoginUserField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool autoLoginUserSpecified {
        get {
            return this.autoLoginUserFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.autoLoginUserFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool noChrome {
        get {
            return this.noChromeField;
        }
        set {
            this.noChromeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool noChromeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.noChromeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.noChromeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is some simple code to serialize it.

```
SendDocumentInteractiveOptions sdio = new SendDocumentInteractiveOptions();
sdio.authoringRequested = true;
sdio.autoLoginUser = true;
sdio.noChrome = true;
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SendDocumentInteractiveOptions));
XmlWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(@"g:\test.xml", null);
xmlSer.Serialize(xw, sdio);
xw.Close();
```

And here is the resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?&gt
&ltSendDocumentInteractiveOptions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

So what am I missing here. Why are my public properties not getting serialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an old question, but oh well.  I think the solution might be in another question ["Why isn't my public property serialized by the XmlSerializer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575432/why-isnt-my-public-property-serialized-by-the-xmlserializer).  Part of the answer lists reasons why an attribute would not be serialized and in that list is

- it has a public bool FooSpecified {get;set;} property that returned false

In your code, you set the various Boolean values but set the related specified values.  I was facing a similar issue and setting the specified value fixed it for me.