# ShouldSerialize*() vs *Specified Conditional Serialization Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am aware of both of the ShouldSerialize* pattern and the *Specified pattern and how they work, but is there any difference between the two?

Are there any "gotchas" using one method vs the other when certain things should be serialized conditionally?

This question is specific to the usage of `XmlSerializer`, but general information regarding this topic is welcome as well.

There is very little information on this topic out there, so it may be because they perform the exact same purpose and it's a style choice.  However, it seems strange that the .NET implementers would analyze the class via reflection and look for either/both patterns to determine how the generated serializer behaves since it slows down the generation of the serializer unless it's just a backwards compatibility artifact.

**EDIT:**  For those unfamiliar with the two patterns if either the `*Specified` property or `ShouldSerialize*` method returns true, then that property is serialized.

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }

//*Specified Pattern
[XmlIgnore]
public bool MyPropertySpecified { get{ return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.MyProperty); } }

//ShouldSerialize* Pattern
public bool ShouldSerializeMyProperty()
{
     return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.MyProperty);
}
```

Comment: This is intentionally undocumented, they want you to use attributes instead.  This "feature" probably snuck into XmlSerializer because of an early version of the Winforms designer or an unfinished plan to move to something equivalent to XAML.  That's a guess.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting.  The *Specified pattern is briefly mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) in the Controlling Generated XML section of the remarks in the `XmlSerializer` class documentation, but nothing on the ShouldSerialize*() pattern.  Unfortunately, attributes don't work when the serialization is conditional.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The intent of the `{propertyName}Specified` pattern is documented in [XML Schema Binding Support: MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx).  It was added to support an XSD schema element in which:

- The **`<element>`** element is involved.
- **minOccurs** is zero.
- The **maxOccurs** attribute dictates a single instance.
- The data type converts to a value type.

In this case, [`xsd.exe /classes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) will automatically generate (or you can manually generate) a property with the same name as the schema element and a `{propertyName}Specified` boolean get/set property *that tracks whether the element was encountered in the XML and should be serialized back to XML.*  If the element is encountered, `{propertyName}Specified` is set to `true`, otherwise `false`.  Thus the deserialized instance can determine whether the property was unset (rather than explicitly set to its default value) in the original XML.

The inverse is also implemented for schema generation.  If you define a C# type with a pair of properties matching the pattern above, then use `xsd.exe` to generate a corresponding XSD file, an appropriate `minOccurrs` will be added to the schema.  For instance, given the following type:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public decimal Something { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool SomethingSpecified { get; set; }
}
```

The following schema will be generated, and vice versa:

```xml
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ExampleClass" nillable="true" type="ExampleClass" />
  <xs:complexType name="ExampleClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Something" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that, while `xsd.exe` is documented only to generate automatically a `{propertyName}Specified` property for value type properties, `XmlSerializer` will respect the pattern when used manually for reference type properties.

You might ask, why does `xsd.exe` not bind to a `Nullable<T>` in this case?  Perhaps because:

- Nullables are used to support the [`xsi:nil="true"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) attribute instead.  See [Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx).
- Nullables were not introduced until .Net 2.0, so maybe it was too late to use them for this purpose?

You need to be aware of this pattern because `xsd.exe` will sometimes generate it for you automatically, however the interaction between a property and its `Specified` property is weird and liable to produce bugs.  You can fill up all the properties in your class, then serialize to XML and lose *everything* because you didn't also set set the corresponding `Specified` properties to `true`.  This "gotcha" comes up here from time to time here, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776592/why-is-my-type-not-being-serialized-correctly-by-the-xmlserializer) or [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900089/is-having-minoccurs-0-sufficient-to-cause-net-to-create-a-xxxspecified-field).

Another "gotcha" with this pattern is that, if you need to serialize your type with a serializer that does not support this pattern, you **may** want to manually suppress output of this property during serialization, and **probably will** need to manually set it during deserialization.  Since each serializer may have its own custom mechanism for suppressing properties (or no mechanism at all!), doing this can become more and more burdensome over time.

(Finally, I'm a little surprised that your `MyPropertySpecified` works successfully without a setter.  I seem to recall a version of .Net 2.0 in which a missing `{propertyName}Specified` setter would cause an exception to be thrown.  But it's no longer reproducible on later versions, and I don't have 2.0 to test.  So that might be a third gotcha.)

Support for the `ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}()` method is documented in [Properties in Windows Forms Controls: Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx).  As you can see the documentation is in the Windows Forms section of MSDN not the `XmlSerializer` section, so it is, in fact, semi-hidden functionality.  I have no idea why support for this method and the `Specified` property both exist in `XmlSerializer`.  `ShouldSerialize` was introduced in [.Net 1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and I *believe* that MinOccurs binding support was added in [.Net 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so perhaps the earlier functionality didn't quite meet the needs (or taste) of the `xsd.exe` development team?

Because it is a method not a property, it lacks the "gotchas" of the `{propertyName}Specified` pattern.  It also seems to be more popular in practice, and has been adopted by other serializers including:

- [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)
- [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) (which claims to [supports both patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190167/protobuf-net-conditional-serialization).)

So, which pattern to use?

1. If `xsd.exe` generates a `{propertyName}Specified` property for you automatically, or your type needs to track whether a specific element appeared or not in the XML file, or you need your auto-generated XSD to indicate that a certain value is optional, use this pattern and watch out for the "gotchas".
2. Otherwise, use the `ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}()` pattern.  It has fewer gotchas and may be more widely supported.

Answer (score 10):

To add to the very detailed answer by @dbc, I ran into an issue with managing serialization in derived classes. In my situation I had a base class and a derived class where a `Prop` property was overridden.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Prop {get; set;}
}

public class Derived: BaseClass
{
    public string Comp1 {get; set;}
    public string Comp2 {get; set;}
    public override string Prop {get => Comp1 + Comp2; set {}}
}
```

Since the `Prop` property in the derived class is calculated, for the `Derived` class I wanted to serialize `Comp1` and `Comp2` but not `Prop`. It turns out that setting the `XmlIgnore` attribute on the `Prop` property in the `Derived` class does not work and `Prop` is serialized anyway.

I also tried to add a `ShouldSerializeProp` method and a `PropSpecified` property in the `Derived` class, but neither work. I tried setting breakpoints to see if they are called and they are not.

It turns out that the `XmlSerializer` is looking at the original class where the `Prop` property appears for the first time in the class hierarchy to decide whether to serialize a property or not. To be able to control serialization in a derived class, first I had to add a `virtual ShouldSerializeProp` in the `Base` class.

```
public class Base
{
    .....
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeProp() {return true;}
}
```

Then I could override the `ShouldSerializeProp` in the `Derived` class and return false.

```
public class Derived: Base
{
    .....
    public override bool ShouldSerializeProp() {return false;}
}
```

This pattern allows different derived classes to choose what properties from the parent class they serialize. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great point @Tibi.  I asked this question a few years ago, but what I've learned since then is to always make serialization classes like this as sealed unless you know in advance that there is going to be a derived classes due to needing virtual methods.