# C# Serializing XmlElement with XmlText

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have this XML format I need to replicate:

```
<item>
    <attribute1>1</attribute1>
    <attribute2 something="true">
        2
    </attribute2>
    <attribute3 something="false">
        3
    </attribute3>
    <!-- goes on until attribute25 -->
</item>
```

I'm currently using something like this to achieve what I want:

Item.cs:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "item")]
public class Item {

    [XmlElement("attribute1")]
    public CustomElement<string> Attribute1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("attribute2")]
    public CustomElement<string> Attribute2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("attribute3")]
    public CustomElement<string> Attribute3 { get; set; }

    // Etc Etc
}
```

CustomElement.cs:

```
/// <summary>
///     Represents a CustomElement.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type for the value of the element.</typeparam>

public class CustomElement<T>
{
    [XmlIgnore] public T Value;

    [XmlText]
    public T XmlValue => Value;

    public CustomElement()
    {
    }

    public CustomElement(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool? Something { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("something")]
    public bool XmlSomething
    {
        get => Something != null && Something.Value;
        set => Something = value;
    }

    public bool XmlSomethingSpecified => Something.HasValue;

    public static implicit operator CustomElement<T>(T x)
    {
        return new CustomElement<T>(x);
    }
}
```

However, after serializing my `Item` I get:

```
<item>
    <attribute1 />
    <attribute2 />
    <attribute3 />
</item>
```

How do I fix my `CustomElement` class so the value doesn't get lost?

Comment: You are serializing an instance of a class with no data.  So add data to the instance of the class.

Comment: @jdweng The class does have data inside, set by code outside of this code snippet.

Comment: Are you sure?  Error message indicates otherwise.  I suspect you have two instances of the class a you are trying to serialize the one that is empty instead of the one that contains data.

Comment: I've checked the debugger and there is definitely data inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. You are trying to serialize the `XmlValue` member as the element value for the element generated for an instance of `CustomElement<T>`, but you have defined it as a **read-only** [expression-bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements):

   ```
   public T XmlValue => Value;
   ```

   `XmlSerializer` will only serialize public read/write properties and fields, so you must add a setter as well as a getter:

   ```
   [XmlText]
   public T XmlValue { get => Value; set => Value = value; }
   ```

   Alternatively, to simplify your model you could eliminate `XmlValue` entirely and serialize `Value` directly by marking it with `[XmlText]`.  XML serialization attributes can be applied to fields as well as properties.
2. You are trying to suppress serialization of the `<something>` element when the underlying value is `null` using the [`{propertyName}Specified` pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx).  This pattern is primarily used for **tracking** whether or not an associated element is encountered, and so the `xxxSpecified` property must be marked with `[XmlIgnore]`:

   ```
   [XmlIgnore]
   public bool XmlSomethingSpecified => Something.HasValue;
   ```

   Or, since you don't actually need to track the presence of the `<something>` element, you could simplify your model by switching to the [`ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx) pattern:

   ```
   public bool ShouldSerializeXmlSomething() => Something.HasValue;
   ```

   The differences between the two patterns are described in [*ShouldSerialize*() vs *Specified Conditional Serialization Pattern*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838640/3744182).
3. If your `Item` type is going to be the root element of your XML document, you must mark it with [`[XmlRoot("item")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) to make the root element's name be `<item>`:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("item")]
   [XmlType(TypeName = "ci")]
   public class Item
   {
       // Etc Etc
   }
   ```
4. In your c# code you have marked the `XmlSomething` property with `[XmlElement]` but in your XML `something` is shown as an *element*: `<something>true</something>`.

   If you really want it to be an element you must mark `XmlSomething` with `[XmlElement]`:

   ```
   [XmlElement("something")]
   public bool XmlSomething
   {
       get => Something != null && Something.Value;
       set => Something = value;
   }
   ```
5. In your question, you show an example of a `<something>` element with a non-boolean textual value:

   ```
   <attribute3>
       3
       <something>text</something>
   </attribute3>
   ```

   I reckon this is a typo in the question, but if not, you will need to redesign your `CustomElement<T>` type to make `Something` be a `string`.

Sample working [Roslyn .Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFM1bi), and a [second](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TTj7nH) with the suggested simplifications for `CustomElement<T>`, and a [third](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fZHVCN) where `<something>` appears as a child element.

The classes from the second fiddle look like:

```
public class CustomElement<T>
{
    [XmlText]
    public T Value;

    public CustomElement()
    {
    }

    public CustomElement(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool? Something { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("something")]
    public bool XmlSomething
    {
        get => Something != null && Something.Value;
        set => Something = value;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeXmlSomething() => Something.HasValue;

    public static implicit operator CustomElement<T>(T x)
    {
        return new CustomElement<T>(x);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("item")]
[XmlType(TypeName = "ci")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("attribute1")]
    public CustomElement<string> Attribute1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("attribute2")]
    public CustomElement<string> Attribute2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("attribute3")]
    public CustomElement<string> Attribute3 { get; set; }

    // Etc Etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Re 5: It is not a type. My class needs to support serialization of any primitive types like `bool`, `string`, `decimal` and `DateTime`. This is why `CustomElement` is a generic class.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 - OK, but in your `CustomElement<T>` you use the generic parameter for the *element value* not the *`<something>` child element value*.  Was that an error in the question?  The question had other errors including invalid XML syntax, which I fixed.

Comment: Re 4 - That was an error on my part; `something` is an attribute, not an element.

Comment: No, the value of the `<attribute*s>` do map to a `CustomElement<T>::Value`. The value will ultimately be a string, but I needed a way to transparently format `DateTime`s when serialized so this is the solution I've come up with. That custom behaviour is defined in a subclass of `CustomElement<T>`, not shown here.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 - I can't answer a question about something you don't show.  In what you actually show, `XmlSomething` is hardcoded to be a `bool`.  Anyway, is the question *How do I fix my `CustomElement` class so the value doesn't get lost?* answered?  If so you might want to ask another question as the preferred format is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: Terribly sorry for the confusion: the value can be of any type. `<something>` can only be bool. I've edited my question to fix this.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 - then in that case I believe I've answered the question.  Is there a remaining problem?