# Undocumented way to keep a property from being serialized to XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

When you make an object Serializable to XML, if a property marked with the [XmlElement] attribute has a friend with "Specified" on the end of the name (regardless of attributes) like this:

```
[XmlType(TypeName="XmlAble"),Serializable]
public class XmlAble
{
    [XmlElement]
    public DateTime MyDate { get { return MyDateField; } set { MyDateField = value; MyDateSpecified = true; } }
    private DateTime MyDateField;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool MyDateSpecified
    {get;set;}

}
```

that boolean flag will be used to decide whether the first property (MyDate in my example) gets serialized at all.

Play with this example at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eiSGtu) and you will see what I mean.

Why does this operate in such a clunky way (I consider anything based off of string contains on property names to be very clunky), but has no documentation for it?

Comment: Why not use `DateTime?` to make it nullable, and instead of having a field saying whether or not its specified you infer this by whether it's null or not.

Comment: It's documented.  See [XML Schema Binding Support: MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx) (official documentation) and [ShouldSerialize*() vs *Specified Conditional Serialization Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842985/3744182) (Stackoverflow answer discussing it.)