# Remove xml element with xsi:nil="true" C# serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have an XML which has some values and at times there can be null values as shown below: I do not want the nodes with null listed at all in the XML! The elements are set `IsNullable = true` in the class.  Any suggestions as I have tried out many stuffs in Google.. nothing helped!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Materials>
  <Material>
    <MaterialName>ABC</MaterialName>
    <Weight Value="0.303">
      <Weight_A xsi:nil="true" />
      <Weight_B xsi:nil="true" />
    </Weight>
    <Density Value="800">
      <Density_A xsi:nil="true" />
      <Density_B xsi:nil="true" />
    </Density>
    <Volume Value="8771.427" />
  </Material>
  <Material>
    <MaterialName>ABC</MaterialName>
    <Weight>
      <V5_Weight>2.009</V5_Weight>
      <V6_Weight>1.3318154561904</V6_Weight>
    </Weight>
    <Density>
      <V5_density>1000</V5_density>
      <V6_density>663</V6_density>
    </Density>
    <Volume Value="2008771.427" />
  </Material>
</Materials>
```

The class structure is as below:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Weight")]
public class Weight
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight_A", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Weight_A { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight_B", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Weight_B { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Density")]
public class Density
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density_A", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Density_A { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density_B", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Density_B { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Volume")]
public class Volume
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Volume_A")]
    public string Volume_A { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Volume_B")]
    public string Volume_B { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Material")]
public class Material
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MaterialName")]
    public string MaterialName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight")]
    public Weight Weight { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density")]
    public Density Density { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Volume")]
    public Volume Volume { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Materials")]
public class Materials
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Material")]
    public List<Material> Material { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post your classes

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838640/shouldserialize-vs-specified-conditional-serialization-pattern allows more fine-grained control over when properties are serialised, but I suspect you have something wrong with your [XmlAttribute].

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed.  It lacks a definition for the `xsi:` namespace prefix, perhaps because it's a fragment of some larger document.   Most likely it should be `<Materials 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`, can you confirm please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic issue is that you have set `XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable = true`.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute_IsNullable):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) must serialize a member that is set to `null` as an empty tag with the `xsi:nil` attribute set to true.

Thus in theory you could just set it to be false (or don't set it at all) and the [`xsi:nil`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ybce7f69(v=vs.100)) attributes will not be emitted for null values:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Weight")]
public class Weight
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight_A" /*, IsNullable = true*/)]
    public string Weight_A { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight_B" /*, IsNullable = true*/)]
    public string Weight_B { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Density")]
public class Density
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density_A"/*, IsNullable = true*/)]
    public string Density_A { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density_B"/*, IsNullable = true*/)]
    public string Density_B { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, if you do that, you may encounter a problem deserializing legacy XML files, namely that string-valued `xsi:nil` elements will now get deserialized as empty strings rather than `null` strings.  (Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sv2CTT).)  If this becomes a problem, you must leave the `XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable = true` setting and instead use the one of the conditional serialization patterns described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842985/3744182) to *[ShouldSerialize*() vs *Specified Conditional Serialization Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838640/3744182)*:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Weight")]
public class Weight
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight_A", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Weight_A { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeWeight_A() { return Weight_A != null; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Weight_B", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Weight_B { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeWeight_B() { return Weight_B != null; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Density")]
public class Density
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density_A", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Density_A { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDensity_A() { return Density_A != null; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Density_B", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Density_B { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeDensity_B() { return Density_B != null; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Having done this, the `<NodeName xsi:nil="true" />` elements will get mapped to a `null` string during deserialization and skipped entirely during serialization.

Notes:

- Your XML is not well-formed.  It lacks a definition for the `xsi:` namespace prefix, perhaps because it's a fragment of some larger document.  This answer assumes it should be:

  ```
  <Materials 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  ```
- Some elements are not bound to your c# data model at all including:

  ```
  <V5_Weight>2.009</V5_Weight>
  <V6_Weight>1.3318154561904</V6_Weight>
  ```

  And

  ```
  <V5_density>1000</V5_density>
  <V6_density>663</V6_density>
  ```

  This answer does not attempt to address this problem (if it is, in fact, a problem).

Sample fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/URwQOn).

Comment: Thanks!! It worked like a charm!!! I had the xsi: namespace prefix but removed it while posting the question :(