# .NET XMLSerializer ignores attributes on serialize

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xmlserializer, primitive-types

I have a class generated by the xsd.exe tool. It doesn't matter what class, the same problem occurs always which is that every attribute having a type other than string is being ignored when the object is being serialized.

Deserializing the xml generated by the serialize method generates a valid .NET object having all attributes with type other than string are empty (int, bool, etc.)

I tried modifying the xml, adding the attributes and deserializing again. This seemed to work.

Edit:
I have just created a demo schema and generated a C# class using the xsd tool.
My schema looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://PwC.C2C.Schemas.Internal.Schema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://PwC.C2C.Schemas.Internal.Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TestElement1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="AttributeBool" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:attribute name="AttributeString" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="AttributeInt" type="xs:int" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the generated C# class looks like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true,    Namespace="http://PwC.C2C.Schemas.Internal.Schema1")]    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://PwC.C2C.Schemas.Internal.Schema1", IsNullable=false)]

public partial class Root {

    private RootTestElement1 testElement1Field;
    /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public RootTestElement1 TestElement1 {
        get {
            return this.testElement1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.testElement1Field = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true,  Namespace="http://PwC.C2C.Schemas.Internal.Schema1")]
public partial class RootTestElement1 {

    private bool attributeBoolField;

    private bool attributeBoolFieldSpecified;

    private string attributeStringField;

    private int attributeIntField;

    private bool attributeIntFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool AttributeBool {
        get {
        return this.attributeBoolField;
        }
        set {
            this.attributeBoolField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool AttributeBoolSpecified {
        get {
            return this.attributeBoolFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.attributeBoolFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string AttributeString {
        get {
            return this.attributeStringField;
        }
        set {
            this.attributeStringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int AttributeInt {
        get {
        return this.attributeIntField;
    }
        set {
            this.attributeIntField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool AttributeIntSpecified {
        get {
            return this.attributeIntFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.attributeIntFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Interesting are the extra properties added if the specified type of the attribute in the schema is no string. `attributeIntFieldSpecified` and `attributeBoolFieldSpecified`.

These cause the attributes to be ignored when serializing the class and they need to be completely removed or set to true.

Comment: One possibility is that you have some `xxxSpecified` properties.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842985/3744182) to [ShouldSerialize*() vs *Specified Conditional Serialization Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838640/3744182) which states, regarding the `{PropertyName}Specified` pattern, ...

Comment: ... *`xsd.exe` will sometimes generate it for you automatically, however the interaction between a property and its `Specified` property is weird and liable to produce bugs.  You can fill up all the properties in your class, then serialize to XML and lose **everything** because you didn't also set set the corresponding `Specified` properties to `true`.*

Comment: @dbc yes this is a {PropertyName}Sepceified issue. Thanks